# Warning 359 when passing string to char*

Tags: c, mplab

I'm trying to pass a string to a function:

```
void PassString(unsigned char * value)
{
    // ...
}

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        PassString("TEST");
    }
}
```

I'm getting warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types.

Comment: maybe in your env, string literals are `signed char *`?

Comment: Also "TEST" is a constant.

Comment: @GemTaylor True, but unrelated to the warning message in question.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Actually it shouldn't even matter if `char`s are signed are not. `char []` can't be automatically converted to `signed char*` nor to `unsigned char *`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh OK so const conversion might generate a different warning, but a decent C compiler should generate a warning or error for it these days.

Comment: @SouravGhosh string literals must be `char[N]`

Comment: @M.M yes sir, and sign of `char` is implementation specific, is not it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not automatic sir, plain `char` is signed or unsigned, is implementation specific. For an implementation, where plain `char` is `unsigned`, the above code should not produce any warning, I believe.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes but it is a different type to `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Even if the same signedness as one or the other.

Comment: @M.M Completely agree. `char` is the only case I guess where `char` and `signed char` are mentioned to be different types in the standard. `int`, on other hand, is `signed int` - by default, thus, they are same types.

Comment: @ Gem Taylor your answer has worked! const unsigned char * has worked perfect for me. Mark it as answer.

Comment: const unsigned char * merely silences the warning, it does not solve the underlying issue. What compiler do you use? GCC gives a more specific warning: "pointer targets differ in signedness."

Comment: Xc8 compiler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

String literals such as `"TEST"` are of type `char[]` in C.

So change the function to accept `char*`. Or cast the argument to `unsigned char*`, even though that's a less clean solution.

---

**Some history behind `char`**:

The C type system is a bit dysfunctional when it comes to the character types. In the dawn of time when dinosaurs walked the earth, it wasn't specified if `char` should be `signed` or `unsigned` per default.

`signed` made sense because that makes `char` consistent with the larger integer types. `unsigned` also made sense, because there exist no character symbol tables with negative indices.

Upon language standardization, there already existed various compilers that gave `char` different signedness. So it was decided that the signedness of `char` should be implementation-defined. That is: each compiler decides.

For the same reason,  the types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` were stated to be 3 different types. This means that you cannot implicitly convert between pointers to these types. Instead you need to use an explicit conversion by casting.

Only the character types behave this weird. If you take for example `int` and `signed int` they are always compatible and `int` is always signed.

This is a known shortcoming of the C language. The types from the `stdint.h` library are therefore preferred over "raw" character types.

---

**Best practice using character types:**

- Use the type `char` if you are dealing with (up to 8 bit) text strings, and *only* then.
- Use the type `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` if you are dealing with raw binary data or doing type punning etc.
- Use `signed char` or `int8_t` if you are doing signed 8 bit integer arithmetic.
- Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` if you are doing unsigned 8 bit integer arithmetic.
- There is never any danger converting between the various character types unless signedness matters.
- But... be careful when doing any form of arithmetic on these types, since it comes with many pitfalls. See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Answer (score 3):

The string literal being passed is of type `char []` but the argument is given as `unsigned char *`.

So change the type of the argument to `char[]`.

Comment: Or to `char *`.

Comment: “the argument is given as `unsigned char *`” should be “the parameter type is `unsigned char *`”. There is some historic mixing of these terms, but the C standard defines *parameter* as an object declared as part of a function declaration that acquires a value on entry to a function and *argument* as an expression in the parentheses of a function call. In other words, an *argument* is the expression that is passed, and a *parameter* is the container for the thing that is received.

Comment: Although the string literal is of type `char []`, it is not passed to the function. First, it is automatically converted to `char *`, so it is a `char *` that is passed to the function, not a string literal or a `char []`.