# c: type casting char values into unsigned short

Tags: c, casting, char, short

starting with a pseudo-code snippet:

```
char a = 0x80;
unsigned short b;
b = (unsigned short)a;
printf ("0x%04x\r\n", b); // => 0xff80
```

to my current understanding "char" is by definition neither a signed char nor an unsigned char but sort of a third type of signedness.

how does it come that it happens that 'a' is first sign extended from (maybe platform dependent) an 8 bits storage to (a maybe again platform specific) 16 bits of a signed short and then converted to an unsigned short?

is there a c standard that determines the order of expansion?

does this standard guide in any way on how to deal with those third type of signedness that a "pure" char (i called it once an X-char, x for undetermined signedness) so that results are at least deterministic?

PS: if inserting an "(unsigned char)" statement in front of the 'a' in the assignment line, then the result in the printing line is indeed changed to 0x0080. thus only two type casts in a row will provide what might be the intended result for certain intentions.

Comment: How can a `char` be neither `signed` nor `unsigned`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: [INT02-C. Understand integer conversion rules](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)?

Comment: why not just use `signed char` vs. `unsigned char` when you're dealing with numbers, and leave the use of `char` for when you're dealing with characters ?

Comment: @FiddlingBits -- `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are distinct types according to the Standard, so the confusion is understandable. Portable code can't treat a bare `char` as either `signed` or `unsigned` unless that implementation detail is known.

Comment: @David: thanks for the wording "portable code" - thats what i really meant. if you write code for portability then you have to deal with /undecorated/ char as a "third type" - even if its compatible with one of the two other variants - but you will not know at code writing time, only at compile time or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `char` is not a "third" signedness.  It is either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, and which one it is is implementation defined.

This is dictated by section 6.2.5p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  three  types `char` , `signed char` , and `unsigned char` are 
>   collectively  called the *character  types*.  The  implementation 
>   shall  define `char` to  have  the  same  range, representation, and
>   behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

It appears that on your implementation, `char` is the same as `signed char`, so because the value is negative and because the destination type is unsigned it must be converted.

Section 6.3.1.3 dictates how conversion between integer types occur:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than
>   _Bool ,if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  **if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is 
>   converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than 
>   the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.**
>
> *3* Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be 
>   represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined or
>   an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Since the value 0x80 == -128 cannot be represented in an `unsigned short` the conversion in paragraph 2 occurs.

Comment: convert -128 to unsinged short =>
-128 + (USHRT_MAX + 1) = (65535 + 1) - 128 = 65408 = 0xff80
(real world implementation might use different math & logic)

Comment: There is no sign extension anywhere. The conversion to a larger type is a lvalue conversion upon assignment. You quote the correct part of the standard but this is not sign extension. Sign extension is `char c = -128; int i = c; printf("%x", i);` giving 0xffffff80 rather than 0x80.

Comment: To clarify, "It appears that on your implementation, char is the same as signed char, so sign extension happens when the value is cast to a larger type." is only true when the value is cast to a larger _signed_ type. This is not the case here, so this part is incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin Nice clarification.  While on a two's compliment implementation the effect of it the same, it's not necessarily true in the general case.  Updated to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

`char` has implementation-defined signedness. It is either signed or unsigned, depending on compiler. It is true, in a way, that `char` is a third character type, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209930/584518). `char` has an indeterministic (non-portable) signedness and therefore should never be used for storing raw numbers.

But that doesn't matter in this case.

- On your compiler, `char` is signed.
- `char a = 0x80;` forces a conversion from the type of `0x80`, which is `int`, to `char`, in a compiler-specific manner. Normally on 2's complement systems, that will mean that the `char` gets the value `-128`, as seems to be the case here.
- `b = (unsigned short)a;` forces a conversion from `char` to `unsigned short` <sup>1)</sup>. C17 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers then says:

  > Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
  >   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
  >   until the value is in the range of the new type.

  One more than the maximum value would be `65536`. So you can think of this as `-128 + 65536 = 65408`.
- The unsigned hex representation of `65408` is `0xFF80`. No sign extension takes place anywhere!

---

<sup>1)</sup> The cast is not needed. When both operands of `=` are arithmetic types, as in this case, the right operand is implicitly converted to the type of the right operand (C17 6.5.16.1 §2).

Comment: some compilers further depending on their warning level settings will warn on the type conversion - because its sometimes a signed to unsigned conversion that means if the sign bit is set to negative the result will still be positive and thus something undesired has the chance to happen.

Comment: In your footnote, I think you meant that the *right*hand operand of an `=` operator is automatically converted to the type of the *left*hand operand.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr Yeah, such conversions are often fishy indeed. On gcc I belive you have to explicitly use `-Wconversion` to get the warnings.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah of course, a typo. Fixed - thanks!